# Rsyslog Forward Custom Log

Tags: linux, logs, rsyslog

I have a app that store the logs under /var/log/app and the logs have the name format appserver-date.log. I need forward this logs with rsyslog to another server running rsyslog. I look something about imfile but can I do some "wildcard" configuration with imfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, rsyslog 8.5 and later support wildcards in `$InputFileName`. See @Ian's answer to [Wildcard support for InputFileName in rsyslog?](https://serverfault.com/questions/500724/wildcard-support-for-inputfilename-in-rsyslog)